# Is there an effective way to create extended event data that includes stacktraces in SQL Server on a local db instance?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, extended-events

I read Paul Randal's article on [getting the symbols for SQL Server](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-download-a-sqlservr-pdb-symbol-file/#comment-10124). I have a theory that I could get the extended events to read the symbols from the symbol server catch directory by setting the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable. The only problem is I can't create the right conditions for any data to show up when I create an extended events session with sqlos.spinlock_backoff. I tried the script [in this pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/A/A/DAAD63AF-B06F-4F29-AF1D-68A78102ABF4/SQLServerSpinlockContention.pdf).

I tried [HammerDB](http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/) and I tried [this script](http://www.sqlserverinternals.com/companion/SE_Chapter8code.txt) with adventure works. I don't get any spinlocks. I tried setting max server memory at 256 megs (my default setting on my laptop) and I tried it at 2 gigs. The Extended event session was running, but no data showed up.

Answer (score 3):

The original Extended Event script from that article has some filters on it ( DBCC_CHECK, INDEX_CREATE and SE_REPL_PARTITION_BY_KEY ) which means they won't fire for just any old spinlocks.  I have adapted the script to remove the filters and have successfully captured the callstacks.  This demo script makes a number of assumptions:

- you are not trying to do this on your production server
- you know how to use SQLCMD mode ( SSMS > Query > SQLCMD Mode )
- you know how to use ostress and have it installed
- I'm working with a named instance called sql2012 - you can configure that
- I'm using c:\temp\temp.sql as a scratch file - you can configure that

Demo script.  WARNING!! Do not run on production server

```
-- Spinlock simulation and callstack tracking with Extended Events
:on error exit
USE tempdb
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

CREATE TABLE spinlock_sim ( id INT PRIMARY KEY )
GO
INSERT INTO spinlock_sim VALUES( 1 )
GO

-- Create the sql file to run
!!bcp "SELECT N'SELECT id FROM spinlock_sim'" queryout c:\temp\temp.sql -S.\sql2012 -T -c

-- Reset spinlock stats (SQL 2012 only)
DBCC SQLPERF( 'sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats', CLEAR );
GO

-- Create the event session
CREATE EVENT SESSION [spin_lock_backoff] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.spinlock_backoff( ACTION(package0.callstack) )
ADD TARGET package0.histogram(SET filtering_event_name=N'sqlos.spinlock_backoff',
    source=N'package0.callstack',source_type=(1))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=51200 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=PER_NODE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

-- Start the session
ALTER EVENT SESSION spin_lock_backoff ON SERVER STATE=START
GO

-- Attempt to create the spinlock contention with ostress
-- REM Parameters -E Windows Authentication -S server -Q query -o output directory -n number of connections -r iterations
-- REM eg 50 connections 200 times
!!"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Corporation\RMLUtils\ostress.exe" -E -S.\sql2012 -dtempdb -ic:\temp\temp.sql -q -oc:\temp\ostress.log -n50 -r200 -mstress
GO



--To view the data
--1. Ensure the sqlservr.pdb is in the same directory as the sqlservr.exe
--2. Enable this trace flag to turn on symbol resolution
DBCC TRACEON (3656, -1)
GO

--Get the callstacks from the bucketize target
select event_session_address, target_name, execution_count, cast (target_data as XML)
from sys.dm_xe_session_targets xst
inner join sys.dm_xe_sessions xs on (xst.event_session_address = xs.address)
where xs.name = 'spin_lock_backoff'
go

-- Look at spinlocks
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats
ORDER BY backoffs DESC
GO

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE spinlock_sim
GO
DBCC TRACEOFF (3656, -1)
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION spin_lock_backoff ON SERVER STATE = STOP
GO
DROP EVENT SESSION spin_lock_backoff ON SERVER
GO
```

If your pdb is not in the right place you will only see hex values instead of method names (like mine), but you get the idea.  Here's what I captured:
[image: Extended Events spinlock callstack]

HTH

Comment: .pdb files are now available for SQL Server 2012 SP1 build 3128 so you can get a more meaningful-looking callstack.  You will need .pdb files for sqlservr, sqlmin and sqllang for it to work properly.